# Error while trying to install tomcat?

Tags: sql-server, apache, tomcat

While trying to install server in eclipse, it shows an error. Does anyone know how to enable server? Please help me in fixing the issue.

Comment: What errors do u get? How did you tried to install it? We dont even know what you tried yet so how should we be able to say what you did wrong?

Comment: @JavaBanana1993 ERROR:  SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Dservlet]]

Comment: WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Dservlet' did not find a matching property.

Comment: i think there are two possible reasons.. 

1. wrong path (check for a tutorial to set it)
2. problem in your web.xml descriptor (check for the "/" in your <url-pattern>/...</url-pattern>

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the path to the tomcat??

Set the path it will go.

Comment: @praveen i downloaded tomcat 7.0.42 and jdk 7 eclipse juno. I have doubt in setting path..